# What does Django return when it cannot find an object?

Tags: python, django

I am doing a query on the database, and I want to do something if the query returns nothing, but I get an error:

```
user = User.objects.get(name=Jack)
if (user == NULL):
    # something
```

I get a User matching query does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

It [throws an exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get). Perhaps you should try [catching it](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: If you want to show a 404 error if the object doesn't exist, there is a shortcut function [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404).

Answer (score 4):

Django doesn't 'return' anything, it throws an error instead, so you are not getting to your if test.

Instead surround the code in a try catch, like this

```
    try: 
      user = User.objects.get(name="Jack")
    except User.DoesNotExist:
      user = None
```

edit: oops, python gets me every time ;)

Comment: >>> null
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Comment: danke, I forget some of the python quirks at times.

Comment: What library do I need to include to get this working? I am getting this error: global name 'Event' is not defined

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use something like this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#get

```
try:
    user = User.objects.get(name="Jack")
except User.DoesNotExist:
    print "User does not exist"
```

If you are just going to 404 the page you may want to use the following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

user = get_object_or_404(User, name="Jack")
```